# Programmatically Trigger a Pattern Card/Profile Card in a selected content in Sitecore

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

I have a task wherein I need to create a functionality that may need to trigger a pattern card programmatically if a specific radio button (where an item is assigned to this with a profile card) is selected and a submit button is clicked.

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this?

I am a newbie on this matter please respect.

Thanks

Comment: You want to change the user pattern programmatically?

Comment: Hmm I have a predefined pattern cards set for testing and would like to check if it can somehow match on one of it by triggering the pattern card.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to be able to boost the user pattern, you may use the below code.

```
public static void BoostUserPattern(Session userSession, string patternName)
{
    var patternCards = // Get your predefined pattern cards

    var patternCard = // Get the specific pattern you want from the list

    if (patternCard == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var profile = Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles[patternCard.Parent.Parent.Name];

    BoostUserPattern(userSession, patternCard, profile);
}

public static void BoostUserPattern(Session session, Item patternCard, Profile profile)
{
    if (patternCard != null && !patternCard.Name.Equals(profile.PatternLabel))
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField xmlData = patternCard.Fields["Pattern"];
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = xmlData.Xml;

        XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("key");
        var scores = new Dictionary<string, float>();

        foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
        {
            if (childrenNode.Attributes != null)
            {
                scores.Add(childrenNode.Attributes["name"].Value, 0);
            }
        }

        // Set a score value here
        scores[patternCard.Name] = 5;

        profile.Score(scores);

        profile.PatternId = patternCard.ID.ToGuid();
        profile.PatternLabel = patternCard.Name;

        UpdateBehaviorProfile(session);
    }
}

private static void UpdateBehaviorProfile(Session session)
{
    var profileConverterBase = BehaviorProfileConverterBase.Create();

    if (session?.Contact == null || Tracker.Current.Interaction == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    session.Contact.BehaviorProfiles.RemoveAll();

    foreach (var profileName in session.Interaction.Profiles.GetProfileNames())
    {
        var profile = session.Interaction.Profiles[profileName];

        if (!IgnoreInteractionProfile(profile))
        {
            var matchedBehaviorProfile = profileConverterBase.Convert(profile);

            session.Contact.BehaviorProfiles.Add(matchedBehaviorProfile.Id, matchedBehaviorProfile);
        }
    }
}

private static bool IgnoreInteractionProfile(Profile profile)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(profile, "profile");

    return false;
}
```

When the user clicks on the radio and submit the value, you trigger the method `BoostUserPattern(Session userSession, string patternName)`. The code will set the pattern to the user.

**UPDATE**

You can retrieve the predefined pattern cards by fetching them from Sitecore. Example:

```
var patternCards = Context.Database.GetItem("Path of your Pattern Container Item").Children;
```

By using the parameter `patternName`, you can perform a query from the list `patternCards`. Example:

```
var patternCard = patternName.ToLower().Equals("Pattern A")
                ? patternCards.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.ToLower().Equals("Pattern A"))
                : patternCards.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.ToLower().Equals("Pattern B"));
```

Note that you can already have a list or some values in a config file where you can read from it and the do the comparison.

Pattern A and B are as shown below

[image]

Comment: Forgot to add some comments. Thanks @Hishaam Namooya as I've got an idea for the problem I had. I also found this [link](http://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2017/06/how-to-trigger-xdb-pattern-cards-using.html) useful to the one I am working

Comment: How do you get the predefined pattern cards?   And get the specific pattern you want from the list?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code please see updated section

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I am not following what Pattern A and Pattern B are?  I thought "patternName" was the name of the pattern you are trying to boost?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code please see image attached and you need to retrieve the Pattern Card Item to be able to boost the user pattern. If you see the last piece of code, from the list of pattern cards, it will return the Pattern Card A if the name matches the Pattern A and so on

Comment: Then wouldn't the code just be?   `var patternCard =  patternCards.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.ToLower().Equals(patternName));`

Comment: @eat-sleep-code yeah. The code I've provided was one from one of my modules I was working

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you have a pattern configured in Sitecore and you would like to test to see if the visitor matches that pattern. If that is the case and all you want to do is check to see what pattern the visitor currently matches then the below should be what you are looking for:

```
// get the name of the pattern
Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles[profileName].PatternLabel;
// get the ID of the pattern
Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles[profileName].PatternId;
```

If you're looking to actually change the visitor's scores, then code like @HishaamNamooya's or any other code that modifies scores and ends in the below (called by Hishaam's code as well) will do:

```
// get the profile - I didn't, but be sure to null-check
var profile = Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles[profileName]; 

var updatedProfileKeys = ... do your scoring logic here ...
// updatedProfileKeys is now a Dictionary<string,float> with the updated scores to apply

// update the scores on the profile
profile.Score(updatedProfileKeys); 
// update the pattern based on the scores you updated - this is supposed to be called from Score as well, but in my experience it doesn't always update unless you call it explicitly
profile.UpdatePattern();
```

Comment: So when attempting this I'm getting an error from within Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XdbModelExtensions when it tries to resolve with GetProfileKeyByAlias. Any thoughts? (Currently using 9.0.2)